# On mouse click changing selection's background color in tableview PyQt on Linux

Tags: python, pyqt, tableview, pyqt5

I am trying to notify user when something is wrong with the item in the list when it is double clicked.

I used setStyleSheet, only to find out that it does not work on unity and cinnamon, while it works on KDE and i3.

I am not all that savvy with qbrushes or some other stuff I am googling out.

So whats the best way to solve this, so that it works everywhere? Thanks.

Heres a gif of my solution in action.

[image]

Heres the code of it, its pyqt5, python3

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class My_Model_table(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, table_data=[], parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.table_data = table_data

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.table_data)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self.table_data[index.row()]
            return value
        if role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return Qt.AlignCenter

class My_table(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.activated.connect(self.double_click_enter)

    def double_click_enter(self, QModelIndex):
        row = QModelIndex.row()
        self.setStyleSheet('selection-background-color:red;')
        self.alarm = QTimer()
        self.alarm.timeout.connect(self.row_color_back)
        self.alarm.setSingleShot(True)
        self.alarm.start(200)
        return

    def row_color_back(self):
        self.setStyleSheet('')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    data = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
    main_table = My_table()
    main_table.setModel(My_Model_table(data))
    main_table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured out my mistake when I had a look at [qdarkstylesheet](https://github.com/ColinDuquesnoy/QDarkStyleSheet).
Instead of just `selection-background-color` I ought to use `QTableView::item:selected:active`

gif is from ubuntu

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class My_Model_table(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, table_data=[], parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.table_data = table_data

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.table_data)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self.table_data[index.row()]
            return value
        if role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return Qt.AlignCenter


class My_table(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.activated.connect(self.double_click_enter)

    def double_click_enter(self, QModelIndex):
        row = QModelIndex.row()

        self.setStyleSheet(
           '''
           QTableView::item:selected:active {
                background: #00ff00;
            }
           '''
        )

        self.alarm = QTimer()
        self.alarm.timeout.connect(self.row_color_back)
        self.alarm.setSingleShot(True)
        self.alarm.start(200)
        return

    def row_color_back(self):
        self.setStyleSheet('')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    data = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
    main_table = My_table()
    main_table.setModel(My_Model_table(data))

    main_table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try over-riding `mousePressEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent` Here is the modification of your code. I believe this should work in all the desktop environments

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class TableData( QAbstractTableModel ):
    def __init__( self, data = [], parent = None ):
        super( QAbstractTableModel, TableData ).__init__( self, parent )
        self.data = data

    def rowCount( self, parent ):
        return len( self.data )

    def columnCount( self, parent ):
        return 1

    def data( self, index, role ):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.data[ index.row() ]
        elif role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return Qt.AlignCenter

class Table( QTableView ):

    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        super( QTableView, Table ).__init__( self )

    def mousePressEvent( self, mpEvent ) :
        self.setStyleSheet( "QTableView{ selection-background-color: red; }" )
        QTableView.mousePressEvent( self, mpEvent )

    def mouseReleaseEvent( self, mrEvent ) :
        self.setStyleSheet( "QTableView{ selection-background-color: none; }" )
        QTableView.mouseReleaseEvent( self, mrEvent )

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication( sys.argv )

    Gui = Table()
    Gui.setModel( TableData( ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], Gui ) )
    Gui.show()

    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

PS: I have just tried this in KDE/Plasma 5. I do not have a GNOME/Unity interface to check the code.

Comment: nope, does not work on unity, I think the way of of setStyleSheet will not bring success.